# Azure webjob not able to connect to database on virtual machine

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to connect my azure webjob to sqlserver database on a virtual machine. I am trying using Hybrid Connection but for some reason not able to establish connection between the azure webjob and azure vm. Is there anything i need to configure to establish this connection?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

> to establish connection between the azure webjob and azure vm.

If you just want to establish connection between Azure web app and Azure VM(not want to connect to on-prem), I think we should use `VNET Integration`.

About how to configure Vnet integration, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enabling-vnet-integration).

> Is there anything i need to configure to establish this connection?

Are there any error messages about can't establish connection?

The Hybrid Connections feature requires a relay agent in the network that hosts your Hybrid Connection endpoint. Have you configure the **Hybrid Connection Manager**(HCM)?

After the connection is connected, we should use **hostname** to access it.

Comment: Thanks. I want to connect to the sqlserver database on the Azure VM. I tried HCM, but though i use the hostname, the status still shows 'Not connected'. Not sure what am i doing wrong. Is there anything to do on the Inbound/Outbound rules?

Comment: @MukilDeepthi yes, here are the HCM requires:1.TCP access to Azure over ports 80 and 443.2.TCP access to the Hybrid Connection endpoint.3.The ability to do DNS look-ups on the endpoint host and the Service Bus namespace. About "Not connected" do you mean this show in your HCM?

Comment: Thanks HCM on the VM is not showing anything. And the status on the hybrid connection tab in Network->Hybrid Connections in azure says 'Not connected'

Comment: @MukilDeepthi it seems you have not correct to create a new hybrid connection, please follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#add-and-create-hybrid-connections-in-your-app) to configure it.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Ye , thanks for your help at the moment. I am waiting for the admin, who has got access to setup rules in Azure. Once he is back , i will try to setup and come back to your for ur help. Hope you dont mind. thanks